# How does img srcs' internal algorithm work?

Tags: html, image, src

I am curious as to what browsers (Specifically chrome) are doing when you set an img tags src to a path which returns a png binary string vs. if you would call this endpoint manually (Say using Ajax or Axios) and then set the images src to this PNG binary manually. Because the results are different between the two.

I am running a Node/expressJs server, which has an image file which returns from the `images/` path.

```
router.get('images/', async function(req, res) {
  try {
    return await fs
      .createReadStream('./images/sample.png')
      .pipe(res);
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(400).json({ message: err.message });
  }
});
```

This API call will return a PNG binary string.

#### scenario 1 - setting the img src to the endpoint where the PNG lives

If I will set the img element as such `<img src="http://localhost/images/"`

This call will return the PNG binary from my Node server and automatically display everything correctly.

#### scenario 2 - Using axios to request this PNG manually

If however, I would use a library like axios, to call this endpoint manually, I would get back a PNG binary string (In the chrome dev-tools 'network' tab, when looking at repsonse data, I even see a nice preview thumbnail of the image, so something in that panel is also correctly taking the PNG data and displaying it in an img element there). But if I will take this data and try to set it to the src of the image tag, I need to do all kinds of base64 conversions before it will work.

So my question is - What is the internal algo of the img element, for when it receives binary image data from a server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no 'internal algorithm'. `src` is an HTML attribute that expects a URI, whether it is an HTTP URI or a Base64 URI. The reason you have to convert the data to Base64 if you request the image using JavaScript is because this is the most straightforward way to represent binary data as a URI. When the browser sees a Base64 URI, then it just converts it back into binary data and displays it.

Comment: So are you saying that when you set the path in the `src` property it just receives the binary from the response and directly renders it?

Comment: @AdamBen-David Yes

Comment: follow up question here - When I discussed this with someone else they mentioned that transforming binary into a base64 representation will be murder for performance because the image represented in base64 will be huge. I am working on an app that would show a large collection of images for specific users, but I wont have the URIs to these images in advance to 'hard-code' them all to images in the UI. What I was looking to do is simply receive all the images from the server and then set them programmatically to image elements I am generating.

Do you know what is the best-practice for this?

Comment: @AdamBen-David Instead of downloading the image in JavaScript in the browser, use the JS to change the `src` attribute of the `img` tag to point to wherever you are downloading the image from.

Comment: Say that I have 40 images to show in the UI and I dont know before hand what is the URL of each of these images. How should that be handled? Like for example in the FB news feed do you know how they populate with images from your account?

Comment: @AdamBen-David Client-side JavaScript is used to figure out where the images the user needs live (through server queries, through some subroutine, however). Then this same client-side JavaScript changes the `src` attribute of each `<img>` element to point to the URI of the image that should be loaded. When the `src` attribute is changed, the `<img>` will automatically load the image located at the new URI.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197832/discussion-between-adam-ben-david-and-laptou).